# Parsing post data

Tags: php, codeigniter

If :     `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['serialize']);echo '</pre>';`

The result is like this :

```
[
 [
  {
   "id": 67,
   "name": "Justin#London"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Hotel 1",
   "number": 1,
   "children": [
    [
     {
      "id": 97,
      "name": "Christina#Jakarta"
     },
     {
      "id": 99,
      "name": "Megan#Milan"
     }
    ]
   ]
  }
 ]
]
```

I want the results of the post is like this :

```
Christina#Jakarta
Megan#Milan
```

How to parse the post data in order to the results as above?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code attempt? It looks like you need to `json_decode()` and then do a loop to get the `children::name` values

Comment: @Sean, Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnConde, Sorry I don't know if this question has been asked before.